# Cannot mock final class for phpunit tests as it's return type is other final class

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, mocking, phpunit

question in regards of https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase

there's a `final class Auth implements Kreait\Firebase\Contract\Auth` which you cannot mock.
interface is used to create an instance upon dependency injection, and there's no problem to create Mock class which also implements it and use during testing.

problem is that some of the methods have return type of class (not interface!) which is also final, like

```php
public function getUserByEmail(Stringable|string $email): UserRecord;
```

so that you're getting

```
Class "Kreait\Firebase\Auth\UserRecord" is declared "final" and cannot be doubled
```